# Parsing JSON url pictures to iOS not working

Tags: ios, json, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to parse a json-file containing links to images. This is my code:

```
#import "Pictures.h"
#import "DEMONavigationController.h"
#import "PicturesObject.h"

@interface Pictures ()
{
    NSInteger refreshIndex;
    NSArray *images;
    NSMutableArray *jsonIs;
    NSArray *items;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imagesinsta;
}
@end

@implementation Pictures

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Pictures";
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu"
                                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                            target:(DEMONavigationController *)self.navigationController
                                                                            action:@selector(showMenu)];

    // ***************** FETCHING DATA  ******************* //
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"link-to-json.php?image=Image"]];
    NSData *data= [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
    if (data == nil) {
        return;
    }
    NSError* error;
    items = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                            options:kNilOptions
                                              error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Json : %@",jsonIs);

    if (jsonIs != nil) {
        NSMutableDictionary* aDict = jsonIs[0];
        NSString *item_media = [aDict objectForKey:@"link"];
    }

    // ***************** FETCHING DATA  ******************* //
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PicturesObject";

    PicturesObject *cell = (PicturesObject *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PicturesObject" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    // The element in the array is going to be a dictionary. I JUST KNOW THIS. The key for the tweet is "text".
    NSDictionary *item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *item_media = [item objectForKey:@"link"];

    return cell;
}

- (void)issueLoadRequest
{
    // Dispatch this block asynchronosly. The block gets JSON data from the specified URL and performs the proper selector when done.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"link-to-json.php?image=Image"]];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(receiveData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)receiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // When we have the data, we serialize it into native cocoa objects. (The outermost element from twitter is
    // going to be an array. I JUST KNOW THIS. Reload the tableview once we have the data.
    self.tweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.tweets.count;
}

@end
```

This is how my custom PicturesObject table view look like:

[image: PicturesObject]

But when I launch my app I only get a screen like this:

[image: Table View]

Comment: Can you paste the JSON response?

Comment: In NSLog I get: Json : (null) @Ernaidu

Comment: No dude I am asking about data which you are getting i  the data variable . try to change the NSData to NSString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json Data is similar to Dictionary and not an array. Instead of using

`NSArray items`

use

`NSDictionary items`

and then extract the the relevant data from dictionary.

Comment: Ok, sounds like a solution. Can you please help me with the code? @vaibhav_15

Comment: jsonDict    =   [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSArray *items = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"Links"];

Comment: Thanks. And this code should be in viewDidLoad method, or? @vaibhav_15

Comment: With this code my app crashes and sends me this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Ya viewDidLoad would be fine I guess. Try it and if it works you can up vote the answer too!!;)

Comment: check the Json data you are getting. The error is telling that either your dictionary or ur array is not getting filled. check for the key subsequent to which the data is located.

Comment: Please check online how a jason, dictionary are structured. It has a key value pair. Start using breakpoints wherever needed. And ya, no one is dumb, its just a start. njoy programming:)

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't find anything. Or I can't find anything I understand... :/ @vaibhav_15

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40913/discussion-between-david-gabor-and-vaibhav-15)